# centos private key and root login

Tags: security, ssh, login, private-key

I wanted to know if it's good practice / secure to allow login as root with ppk (private key) file. (no password).

This server is only for me and no one else is working on it.
Thanks,
Danny

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allowing root login via ssh (even with key authentication) is never a good practice.

Even if this server is truly only for you (and only for non-critical applications), you're still setting your own habits, which you'll be tempted to employ in the future on servers that *aren't* just for you.

It's well worth the effort getting used to connecting as your own user and using sudo to execute commands that require elevated privileges.

Comment: got it :) 1 thing i could never understand is, why sudo if i'm the only user....having to add sudo before each command is annoying...

Comment: Traceability, logging of commands, one more roadblock to prevent you from shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: Even logging in as simple user then doing `su -` is better than nothing in case of multiple people with root password. At least you'll have the user's name who switched to root in audit.log. And I agree with you that adding sudo on every line is annoying. I'd say it's more for one-off commands. I.e. if you're installing a new service (e.g. dhcp) on the server and will be doing a bunch of `vim`, `less`, `tcpdump`, `service` commands one after the other `su -` seems more natural. You just need to take care not to use it for everything (e.g. ssh to another server, wget, ...).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above allowing root login is never good.
Once you are logged in as a different user you can use `su -` and then enter the password to "login" as root (get roots shell) or you can also use `su - username` to login as another user. You lose, however, the auditing capabilities of `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice would be not to allow root login, and if it does need to be allowed (for say, rsyncing backups), the it should be allowed with keys only, and with forcecommand.

Comment: Hi @Cian...can you explain forcecommand?

Comment: ssh forcecommand lets you ignore what a user wants to do, and run a pre-specified command. That means you can have root login, and be forced to run something like rsync to do backups.